# Array of strings which are URL's, can I append more text to each of the strings?

Tags: c#, arrays, string

Array of strings which are URLs, can I append more text to each of the strings?

My array of strings are all URLs, I need to add the same string to the end of each one.  This why each is an API call.  I am already removing a bit of text from the end of each now I just need to add `/_apis/release/releases?minCreatedTime=2021-08-31&api-version=5.0`

I tried using `.Append` the same way that I used `.Replace` but that does not seem to work.

```
var jsonString = response.Content;        
var jsonDeserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonString);
var projects = jsonDeserialized.value.Select(value => value.url).ToArray();

for (int i = 0; i < projects.Length; i++)
{
    projects[i] = projects[i].Replace("_apis/projects/", string.Empty);
}
        
foreach (var url in projects)
{
    Console.WriteLine(url);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Change it like so `projects[i] = $"{projects[i].Replace("_apis/projects/", string.Empty)}/_apis/release/releases?minCreatedTime=2021-08-31&api-version=5.0";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even need the array:

```
var stringToAdd = "/_apis/release/releases?minCreatedTime=2021-08-31&api-version=5.0";
var jsonString = response.Content;
        
var jsonDeserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonString);
var projects = jsonDeserialized.value.
                  Select(value => value.url).
                  Select(url => url.Replace("_apis/projects/", string.Empty).
                  Select(url => url + stringToAdd);

foreach (var url in projects)
{
    Console.WriteLine(url);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

And of course you can consolidate the `Select()` operations:

```
var stringToAdd = "/_apis/release/releases?minCreatedTime=2021-08-31&api-version=5.0";
var jsonString = response.Content;
        
var jsonDeserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonString);
var projects = jsonDeserialized.value.
                  Select(value => value.url.Replace("_apis/projects/", string.Empty) + stringToAdd);

foreach (var url in projects)
{
    Console.WriteLine(url);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

If you *really* want an array, wait until after the last operation. This will save a lot of memory use. If you think you want the array because you need to pass it to a method that expects a `string[]`, *change the method* to expect an `IEnumerable<string>` instead (including any internal code changes to the method to make that work). Anything else that calls this method using an array will *still work*.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried using .Append the same way that I used .Replace but that does not seem to work.

If you had code like:

```
var s = "Hello ";
var t = s.Append("world");
```

It won't work. String itself has no Append method; the Append you see in intellisense is probably from LINQ, which adds a method Append to strings purely because strings can optionally/alternatively be treated as a sequence of `char`acters. The code above is faulty because the string `s` is not treated as a string when used with Append but bunch of chars. As such it is expected that the thing you pass into Append is also a (single) char, and "world" is a string, not a char. You might have seen some cryptic error about not being "able to infer type arguments from the usage"..

Anyways, just use + to concatenate your string on to the result of your Replace :

```
for (int i = 0; i < projects.Length; i++)
{
  projects[i] = projects[i].Replace("_apis/projects/", string.Empty) + "/_apis/release/releases?minCreatedTime=2021-08-31&api-version=5.0";
}
```

Comment: string is an `IEnumerable<char>`, and `IEnumerable<T>` has Append(). It will create the appropriate sequence of character, but not as a string.

Comment: *it will create the appropriate sequence of character* - though that would be Concat, I think..